# Display PHP echo in a textarea using AJAX/jQuery?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am trying to display a PHP echo in a textarea using AJAX that auto refreshes every second. So far everything I do this doesn't want to work and I get nothing in the textarea.

Here is my code:

```
<?php
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($db_conx,"SELECT message FROM chat WHERE asker = ?");
$stmt->bind_param('s', $asker);

 $stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($message);

/* fetch values */

while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    $currvalue[] = array('message'=>$message);
}

echo $message;

echo '333333333';
?>
```

HTML code:

```
<textarea id="chattercontent" style="width:90%; height:150px; resize:none;" readonly></textarea>
```

AJAX/jQuery code:

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        function load() {
            $.ajax({ //create an ajax request to load_page.php
                type: "GET",
                url: "file.php",
                dataType: "text", //expect html to be returned                
                success: function (response) {
                    $("#chattercontent").html(response);
                    setTimeout(load, 1000)
                }
            });
        }

        load();
    });
    </script>
```

What happens with the code above, I get the `echo '333333333';` in my textarea like so `333333333` which is good and fine. But I don't get the `echo $message;` in my textarea.

I have checked to see if the MySQL table and column to see if its not empty and I can confirm that it is not empty and it has some values in it.

I also, viewed the `file.php` page directly from the browser and it does `echo $user_message;` properly. But it doesn't get echoed in AJAX call and in my textarea.

Could someone please advise on this issue?

Comment: And did you log the response to the console, if you're getting `333333` and not the message, it's probably because `$message` is empty

Comment: @adeneo, $message is not empty because when i view the page directly from the browser, i get the $message echoed properly. so i know its not empty.

Comment: were in your code is $message being assigned?

Comment: Can you show us what `$message` contains. And what you see when you view the `.php` file directly? Also can you check the `html` of the page and the `textarea` tag? (when you load it)

Comment: the $message contains the users input which has been saved in the mysql database. I see whatever has been stored in the mysql database when I view the .php page directly. I can see the html page and the textarea but there is nothing in it that indicates that the $message was/is in it. I get no errors whatsoever. but at the same time, i get no $message echo-ed in my textarea. if I remove the AJAX and use the form action, I get the $message echo-ed properly on my page! this is the strangest thing I ever encountered!

Comment: Ok can you add a semicolon at the end of `setTimeout(load, 1000)` this line and check again. Computers don't make mistake there is definitely something wrong it's just a matter of finding it. Can you post the html of the page after you get `333333` in your textarea. Put it in pastebin or something.

Answer (score 0):

Your $message variable is not being assigned anywere

replace your echo $message; with

```
print_r($currvalue);
```

and you will see your output.

In other words, you $message variable contains nothing! (assign it something with `$message = 'someting';`)

Comment: Yes I was thinking the same thing! The actual message should be in `$currvalue['message']`

Comment: Yeapp that's true, although he/she (shell) is claiming the var is being echoed properly and I see it assigned nowhere!

Comment: But he said that he viewed the file directly and it did echo the variable correctly

Comment: I do not beleive that unless he shows us were it is being assigned. I tried this code and it works nowhere without assigning the var something!!

Comment: Ofcourse, but one more thing to ponder upon: if the variable was not assigned, the script would give an error of undefined variable

Comment: @OliverMGrech, I don't think there is any reason for me to lie if i am trying to get help. so if you don't BELIEVE me then that is your problem I'm afraid. as I said, i am able to get echoed $message when i see the page from the browser.

Comment: Do not get me wrong my friend I'm trying to give you the help you requested. $message is not being assigned anywere in the script you provided so that means there is something weird going on as your script doesn't have anywere $message = ... thus on my machine it's outputting nothing, not even without AJAX. Do you have more code prior to the one you pasted?

Comment: oh sorry the $stmt->bind_result($message); is doing it... check that you have a Database initialization in your ajax script!!! (an include to the file with your db user name/pw ) :)