# AJAX load content using link instead of button?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to load content of a URL which is in a href of a Link using AJAX/JQUERY.

For some reason, the AJAX doesn't get executed and when i click on the Link, the URL will open in a new window!

but I need to load the content of URL on the same page that has the AJAX without opening a new window!

this is my current code:

```
<div id="content"></div>

<a id='listc'  class='lisitem' href='file.php?id=".$id."' >".$id."</a>
```

and the AJAX:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#listc").click(function() {        
    $("#content").load(this.href);

    return false;
});
</script>
```

just to clarify, I do have the jquery lib included in my page header and I am using it for other stuff on the same page. so the issue is not that.

could some please advise on this issue?

Thanks

Comment: Does this have anything to do with [your other question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25712011/)? This btw `<a id='listc'  class='lisitem' href='file.php?id=".$id."' >".$id."</a>` why the quotes around `".$id."`? Are you in PHP or not?

Comment: @Fred-ii-, No, as you can see they are totally different questions!!!

Comment: @Fred-ii- yes, I am using PHP and quotes or no quotes, it works fine and it gets the data from the database on the page.. it has nothing to do with the AJAX not working.

Comment: I didn't say if "using" PHP, I meant are you "in/inside" PHP while using that; *two different animals altogether* ;)

Comment: Yes, I am inside PHP.

Comment: Looks to me that none of the answers given *so far* below are able to fix your *new* problem. Q: Did you fix the other problem you had in your other question?

Comment: @Fred-ii- so far nothing worked for this problem... and yes the other issue i had was solved. lets stay on the topic of this question for now and I will post an answer to the other question from lastnight when i get a chance.

Answer (score 3):

You need to prevent the default action of the link:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#listc").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();   
    $("#content").load(this.href);

    return false;
});
</script>
```

Comment: still the same I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0):

Give the following a try:

```
document.getElementById('listc').addEventListener('click', function() {
   $("#content").load(this.href);
   return false;
});
```

***UPDATE***

Change:

```
<a id='listc'  class='lisitem' href='file.php?id=".$id."' >".$id."</a>
```

to:

```
<a id="listc" class="listitem" data-id="<?= $id; ?>" href="#"> <?= $id; ?></a>
```

And AJAX to:

```
$(document).delegate('.listitme','click',(function() {
  var id = $(this).data('id');
  $('#content').load('file.php?id=' + id);
  return false;
}
```

or:

```
$(document).delegate('.listitme','click',(function() {
      var id = $(this).data('id');
      $.post('file.php', {id : id}, function(answer) {
          $('#content').html(answer);
      });
    }
```

Comment: still the same I'm afraid.

Comment: I can't change the href as I am inside a PHP page.

Comment: there is a syntax error in both AJAX codes you've added.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do something with your AJAX return :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#listc").click(function() {        
    $("#content").load(this.href, function(result){
        alert("AJAX done");
    });

    return false;
});
</script>
```

Comment: still the same. and because I get redirected to the new tab on clicking on the button, I wont even get alert();

Answer (score 0):

You can change the `href` from the actual page, to a `javascript:` call. This way, you wouldn't have to concern about the default link redirect.

```
<a id='listc'  class='lisitem' href=javascript:LoadFunction('file.php?id=".$id."'); >".$id."</a>
```

JS:

```
function LoadFunction(url) {
    $("#content").load(url, function(result){
        //something
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like that :
When you click on the link, do an AJAX call then print the result in your container.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#listc").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
           url: $(e.currentTarge).attr('href'),
           complete: function () {
              // remove loading status if neeed
           },
           success: function (response) {
               $("#content").html(response)
           },
           error: function() {
              //manage error here
           }

        });
    });    
</script>
```